# printer driver implementation in java

Tags: java, frameworks, printing, driver

I need to implement a custom printer driver which does the following in the backgroud:

1. Create a PDF document of the document to print
2. Send the created PDF document to a predefined email address OR
   call a web service and transmit the document there

The pinterdriver should be available for windows and mac osx. My prefered implementation language is Java.

Is this possible with Java?
Are there frameworks available which reduce the coding effort to a minimum?

Comment: No, you cannot create (Windows) printer drivers in Java, because they (like any Windows drivers) must be built using [WDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Kit), which comes with a C++ compiler, AFAIK. And, OS X doesn't officially support Java at all any more.

Comment: @Joonas Pulakka, rubbish! OS X supports Java. My colleague runs Java 6 on his latest Mac OS X. And have your heard of [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: [As of the release of Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3, the version of Java that is ported by Apple, and that ships with Mac OS X, is deprecated](http://www.macrumors.com/2010/10/21/apple-discontinuing-java-installation-packages-for-mac-os-x/). It's, of course, still possible to use Java on OS X via the [openjdk project](http://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/oracle_and_apple_announce_openjdk_project_for_osx), but the official support has been dropped. It's Java that supports OS X now, not other way round. And yes, I have actually done quite some JNI (C) code. What about it?

Comment: @Joonas in Lion, the second the OS detects you are trying to run a Java app the OS prompts you to download Java, Apples implementation of Java.  It is still being supported and updated to boot.

However, long term the APPLE PROVIDED JDK/JRE will go away, however Apple is working on merging the OS X specific stuff with Open JDK with the ultimate target being an Open JDK that integrates well with the OS X environment.  This will allow OS X users to quickly get the latest and greatest JRE and ensure better cross-platform support.

Comment: @Joonas Pulakka, oops...sorry, I never knew Apple boys were affected. As for the printer driver. The OP doesn't want to write OS specific driver but wants to capture the print and converts it to PDF and email it to someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure "driver" is really the word you are looking for here?  Usually when one says a print driver they actually mean something that translates document data into commands for a printer.  I think you are really looking for something of a pre-processor.

In any case, if you want it to look like a printer to the OS, it will be almost impossible to do purely in Java.  Your best bet would be to create drivers for each of the platforms that use JNI(or just invoke a JVM), do your processing, then forward it on to the printer.

Although I do not know if a similar approach will work on Windows, what you want to do is almost trivial to do on OS X.  Apple already provides a cups-pdf service that converts any printable document into a pdf, all you have to do is take that output, forward it to where it needs to go, then forward it to a printer, no need to do anything in Java.

For an example of how to do this, check out the following project:

https://bitbucket.org/codepoet/cups-pdf-for-mac-os-x/downloads

Comment: I call it "Driver" because the user should select a printing device, and than "print" the document. The driver than will ask for a fax number and than send an email in the background to our faxserver which finally send a fax to the entered number. Do you also know frameworks/samples for winows?

Comment: cups-pdf is open source AFAIK, meaning you could probably compile it and run it under windows, but I'm not sure.  Its certainly not as deeply integrated with the OS as it is with OS X(in OS X you can essentially print anything to a pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Windows can be configured to send printer output to a file. You can create a printer in Windows that uses a PostScript driver, and writes it to c:\myfile.txt
In Windows: Add a Printer, Select Local printer, Select Create a new port, and type the file name (Full path) you want to use. Then pick the driver you want, which your Java program will have to parse. Generic text could be useful in some cases, or Postscript if you need all that formatting, and can handle parsing it.

Unlike the "File:" option under existing ports, it will not ask the user for a filename. It will just automatically save to the specified file every time.

Your Java program can monitor this file for changes, and then process the data it receives.